# Can an EU national travel to the US on an EU passport that expires in 2 months?

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, eu-citizens

I need to travel to the US next week on business however my passport expires in June. Are there any restrictions that would stop me from travelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Visa Waiver Program [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program#Passport_validity) (I assume you can join the Visa Waiver Program)

> **Passport validity**
>
> The standard requirement for passport validity is 6 months beyond the
>   expected date of departure from the United States. However, the US has
>   signed agreements with a number of countries to waive this
>   requirement. [[107]](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/104770.pdf)