# Travelling to the us with a eu passport that expires weeks after return

Tags: visas, usa, passports, eu-citizens

Can a EU citizen visit the US on a passport that expires the same month they are visiting?

Visiting: 26th of oct - 9th of Nov

Visa is valid until: 12th of November

Passport is valid until: 22th of November

I realize there is information about this here: http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2014/09/231319.htm and that this question is a duplicate of [Can an EU national travel to the US on an EU passport that expires in 2 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25851/can-an-eu-national-travel-to-the-us-on-an-eu-passport-that-expires-in-2-months).

**However** the answer given & information on this page states something about US citizens visiting EU, not the other way around. Do EU citizens visiting the US also need to have a passport that has a validation longer than 6 months?

I checked all Dutch documentation I could find on this, they have great lists of what countries require 3 or 6 months validity, but the US is in none of them. Does this mean there is no validity requirement?

[This Dutch website](https://www.jandoets.nl/Hoe_lang_moet_mijn_paspoort_geldig_zijn) claims I can travel as long as I leave the country before my passport expires. But it is no official source.

Also, the answer quotes this part:

> However, the US has signed agreements with a number of countries to waive this requirement.

And the given link goes to a 404 page. How do I find out what countries are waived? I will be visiting from The Netherlands.

*The reason why I am asking by the way is because if I do need a new passport, I also need a new ESTA. And this means no returning esta line access, extra costs and extra time.*

Comment: FYI the returning ESTA line doesn't require that you be returning on the *same* ESTA. You just need to have visited at least once since 2008.

Comment: Side note: the airline may resist boarding if the check-in agent is unfamiliar with the rules/exceptions. Not saying it would be a game over situation, but one that might need preparation such as a printout or whatever. They *should* know, especially on a popular route like that, but they're only human. Experienced similar once, got it sorted with a friendly supervisor fairly quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a 6 month validity on your dutch passport to visit the USA.

> No. The United States and The Netherlands have a bilateral agreement
>   whereby Dutch passports are recognized as valid for return to The
>   Netherlands for a period of six months beyond the expiration date
>   specified in the passport (and vice versa for American passports).
>   However, the passport must still be valid for the length of the
>   proposed trip. Thus, if planning a two month stay, the passport
>   presented at the airport must be valid for at least that two month
>   period, but does not have to be still valid for six months.

source : http://amsterdam.usconsulate.gov/niv_ppt_req.html

Answer (score 3):

I actually got the answer from a friend, so I decided to post it here in case anyone is wondering the same.

The Netherlands is on the list of countries that are waived for the requirement.

So, if you're visiting the US from The Netherlands, your passport does not need to be valid for 6 months. However, you must assure that your passport is valid until after your return.

Source: http://amsterdam.usconsulate.gov/niv_ppt_req.html